# Is it possible to handle _bsontype error when do query to mongodb?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, bson

When i try to do a query to mongodb by aggregation with _bsontype key inside $sort stage, for example: `{$sort: {_bsontype: -1}}`, i received an error: **TypeError: Unrecognized or invalid _bsontype: -1**

[Current error example in code after performing aggregation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8OEX.png)

[$sort stage with _bsontype value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGdQQ.png)

I receive _bsontype key from a query params url when doing **GET** request to a specific route and then create specific stages inside some method programmatically.

But when I paste something else instead of **_bsontype** in query params, for example: **_bjontype**, just replace 1 letter, everything works properly, the problem is only with **_bsontype** value.

Does anyone faced with such a problem?